# Determining if a matrix can be made upper triangular via permutations

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be an $n$-dimensional square matrix. I am wondering if there is an efficient way to determine if there exists an upper triangular matrix $B$ that can be obtained by permuting the rows and columns of $A$.

Clearly, if $A$ contains more than $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ non-zero elements then no such $B$ exists.

Comment: There must be a row with at least one nonzero element, and a row with at least two nonzero elements,... and a row with all nonzero elements.  Similarly for columns.  This is stronger than the $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ condition mentioned.

Comment: @vadim. This comment is a complete answer.

Comment: @PVanchinathan, alas it is only a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is [known](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281471293_Obtaining_a_Triangular_Matrix_by_Independent_Row-Column_Permutations) to be NP-complete; it would seem that this result was published less than a year ago.

The link points to a Dec. 2015 paper by Fertin, Rusu, and Vialette, with abstract:

Given a square (0, 1)-matrix A, we consider the problem of deciding whether there exists a permutation of the rows and a permutation of the columns of A such that, after these have been carried out, the resulting matrix is triangular. The complexity of the problem was posed as an open question by Wilf [6] in 1997. In 1998, DasGupta et al. [3] seemingly answered the question, proving it is NP-complete. However, we show here that their result is flawed, which leaves the question still open. Therefore, we give a definite answer to this question by proving that the problem is NP-complete. We finally present an exponential-time algorithm for solving the problem.